# JSON Schema: factoring out properties from "oneOf" and disallowing additional properties

Tags: jsonschema

I want to build some kind of object inheritance structure where some shared properties are defined in a common spec and some properties are specific to sub types but no additional properties are allowed.

Example:

```json
{
    "$id": "https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/schema",
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",

    "$ref": "#/$defs/shape",

    "$defs": {
        "shape": {
            "oneOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/$defs/sphere" },
                { "$ref": "#/$defs/cube" }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "color": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },

        "sphere": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "kind": { "const": "sphere" },
                "radius": { "kind": "number" }
            },
            "required": [ "kind", "radius" ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },

        "cube": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "kind": { "const": "cube" },
                "edge": { "kind": "number" }
            },
            "required": [ "kind", "edge" ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}
```

This example does not work because the `"additionalProperties": false` in shape forbids `kind`, `radius` and `edge` and the `"additionalProperties": false` in the sub types forbid `color`.

I want to allow `{"kind":"sphere", "radius":5, "color":"red"}` and `{"kind":"cube", "edge":3, "color":"green"}` but forbid additional properties. However, I don't want to repeat the `color` spec in all sub types... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this:
[How to merge two json schema without additional properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843324/how-to-merge-two-json-schema-without-additional-properties)
and this:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#unevaluated-properties
which solves the problem.